# Why does $\operatorname{rank}([u_{n-k+1},...,u_n][v_{n-k+1},...,v_n]^*)=k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A\in M_n$ and  the (nonzero) minimum singular 
value of the matrix $A$ has multiplicity $k\ge1$,

$${s_1} \ge {s_2} \ge .... \ge {s_{n - k}} > {s_{n - k + 1}} = .... = {s_n} > 0$$         .

with associated left singular vectors $u_1,u_2,....u_n$ and associated right singular vectors $v_1,v_2,....v_n$ .

List item

It is true that           .

$rank([u_{n-k+1},...,u_n][v_{n-k+1},...,v_n]^*)$=k,  and

$rank([u_1,...,u_n][v_1,...,v_n]^*)$=n?

Comment: Both statements hold since $[u_1,\ldots,u_n]$ and $[v_1,\ldots,v_n]$ are orthogonal/unitary matrices.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp - Please more guide, for first part.

Comment: The product of two orthogonal/unitary matrices is again orthogonal/unitary. The proof is simple. For the second part: The U-matrix is isometric and the V-matrix has rank k. Hence, the V-matrix has k linear independent columns and the U-matrix maps these onto a k-dimensional subspace. Hence, the rank (dimension of image) is k.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp - In part 2 : we know that,  $k-$ column of matrix $U$ are dependent. therefore why does $rank([u_1,...,u_n][v_1,...,v_n]^*)$=n?

Comment: As far as I know, we have the SVD here: $A = U\Sigma V^*$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary and $\Sigma$ diagonal. So, if we consider a $k$-column extraction of $U_k$ of $U$ (same for $V$) we have that $\operatorname{rank}(U_kV_k^*) = k$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma$ be a singular value of $A$ with respective left- and right singular vectors $u$ and $v$. We can assume that $\|v\|=1$. Then also $\|u\|^2 = \langle u,u\rangle = \sigma^{-1}\langle Av,u\rangle = \sigma^{-1}\langle v,A^*u\rangle = \langle v,v\rangle = 1$. We have $Av = \sigma u$ and $A^*u = \sigma v$. Hence, $A^*Av = \sigma A^*u = \sigma^2 v$ and $AA^*u = \sigma^2 u$. Hence $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors of $AA^*$ and $A^*A$, respectively, corresponding to the eigenvalue $\sigma^2$. This means that for different singular values $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ we have that $v_1\perp v_2$ and $u_1\perp u_2$. Hence, in the singular value decomposition $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices.

However, in the original post we have that the smallest singular value is of multiplicity $k$ and nothing is said about whether the corresponding $u_j$'s are orthogonal to each other or only linearly independent (same for the $v_j$'s). So, in principle, we could have $u_{n-k+1} = \ldots = u_n$ (same for the $v_j$'s). Then, of course, both statements are false. They are true if the vectors are chosen to form two ONBs (which they are in the SVD). In summary, the question is undecidable here because there is information missing.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Let $T=[u_{n-k+1},...,u_n][v_{n-k+1},...,v_n]^*$ ,can we say that $Tv_j=0$ for $j=1,2,..,n-k$?

Comment: Hi H.S.The answer is similar to what I wrote above. If, for example, all singular values coincide, then we cannot, unless we add the assumption that all left singular vectors $u_j$ are orthogonal to each other. But if only the singular values $s_1,\ldots,s_{n-k}$ are larger than $s_n$, then we can say this. (Oh, I just saw that the latter is assumed in the original post. So yes, we can. ;o))